# Is it possible to serialize object to JSON using toString method without custom serializer?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have this class:

```
public class JsonUser {

    private final String id;
    private final String email;

    public JsonUser(String id, String email) {
        this.id = id;
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        JsonObject json = new JsonObject();
        json.addProperty("id", user.id());
        json.addProperty("email", user.email());
        return json.toString();
    }

}
```

As you see, `JsonUser::toString` returns a JSON string. I'm wondering if there is any way to tell Jackson to serialize `JsonUser` by calling `toString` method, instead of by fields/properties.

Is it possible to achieve that **without using `@JsonSerialize`** with a custom serializer?

Comment: I think if you annotate the `toString()` method with `@JsonValue` that Jackson will use that for serialization. Similarly, you can annotate a String constructor with `@JsonCreator` for deserialization.

Comment: @Baldy Thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for. Post it as answer and I will accept

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you annotate the `toString()` method with `@JsonValue` Jackson will use that for serialization. You can also annotate a String constructor with `@JsonCreator` for deserialization.